Is it possible to use Dataflow for streaming row edits into BigQuery?
I have an ETL flow where I need to combine two Pub/Sub messages on a key and write these into BigQuery. One of the message types is the parent; I am working on payment processing, and this is an order or a payment, for example. The other is the child; this is an update to the payment ("Authorized", "Paid", etc).
I would like to use Dataflow to combine on the key and write to BigQuery, where these updates are added elements to the original transaction. The schema in BigQuery looks something like this:



name
description
type
mode




id
UUID for transaction
String
Single


amount
transaction amount
Integer
Single


events
collection of all events that have occurred on the transaction
Record
Repeated



...
and within the events record, it has something like:



name
description
type
mode




event_id
UUID for this event
String
Single


transaction_id
UUID tying back to transaction
String
Single


event_type
an enum specifying if it is an Authorization, etc.
Integer
Single



...
In other words, each event-type Pub/Sub message will be matched with the appropriate transaction and then appended to the events field in the BigQuery table.
But I've never done this before in BigQuery via Dataflow:  I have written to BigQuery using the WriteToBigQuery function, but it is not obvious to me how I could use that function, or something like it, to edit the row, appending the new event that I would like to append.
I need this type of functionality so that the transaction is available in BigQuery before all events have completed. (In fact, it is not obvious what "completed" may mean, since things like refunds could occur.)
Question

Is it possible to be able to edit a row from BigQuery using Dataflow? Maybe the row can first be read, and then overwritten (in this case simply appending an element to the repeated record field)?

Or does streaming Dataflow only allow for row appends?




I'm assuming I cannot do this directly, since WRITE_TRUNCATE is not allowed. But I was hoping for maybe a clever way around it.

Hi @Mike Williamson, Could you have a look at this stack link, stack link2 let me know if this helps you or  not ?

Thank you!  I will try them and check them out.  I don't think it wil work, because I cannot do upserts (cannot do WRITE_TRUNCATE) since it is streaming. But I will try...
